# Combining (overlaying) ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine 3 ggplots without changing anything about the plots. I trying to just add them to each other but the the colors of the lines changed to be only one color in the legend. Also, I had 6 different types of lines instead of 2. Here is what I have for each plot n1, n2, and n3.

```
x1  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Power1<- c(0.633,0.994,0.998,0.999,1.000,0.422,0.771,0.837,0.888,0.953)
Method1 <- c(rep("Parametric, Case I", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case I", 5))
df1 <- data.frame(Method1, Power1)

n1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Power1,x=x1, color=Method1, linetype=Method1),color="green")+
  ggtitle("Power Plot for Case I, d=2") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Sample size") + ylab("Power") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))


x2  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Power2<- c(0.629,0.986,0.997,0.999,1.000,0.418,0.741,0.809,0.874,0.932)
Method2 <- c(rep("Parametric, Case II", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case II", 5))
df2 <- data.frame(Method2, Power2)

n2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Power2,x=x2, color=Method2, linetype=Method2),color="red")+
  ggtitle("Power Plot for Case II, d=2") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Sample size") + ylab("Power") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))


x3  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Power3<- c(0.599,0.908,0.994,0.999,1.000,0.379,0.613,0.765,0.832,0.917)
Method3 <- c(rep("Parametric, Case III", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case III", 5))
df3 <- data.frame(Method3, Power3)

n3<- ggplot(df3, aes(x3)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Power3,x=x3, color=Method3, linetype=Method3),color="blue")+
  ggtitle("Power Plot for Case III, d=2") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Sample size") + ylab("Power") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Comment: You can remove `,color="green"`, `,color="red"` and `,color="blue"` and run `ggpubr::ggarrange(n1,n2,n3)` after installing `ggpubr` package to combine 3 ggplots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the data frames and use the variable for aesthetic in only a single ggplot call.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Power<- c(0.633,0.994,0.998,0.999,1.000,0.422,0.771,0.837,0.888,0.953)
x1  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Method <- c(rep("Parametric, Case I", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case I", 5))
df1 <- data.frame(Method, Power, x=x1)

x2  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Power<- c(0.629,0.986,0.997,0.999,1.000,0.418,0.741,0.809,0.874,0.932)
Method <- c(rep("Parametric, Case II", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case II", 5))
df2 <- data.frame(Method, Power,x =x2)

x3  <- c(10,30,50,70,100,10,30,50,70,100)
Power <- c(0.599,0.908,0.994,0.999,1.000,0.379,0.613,0.765,0.832,0.917)
Method <- c(rep("Parametric, Case III", 5), rep("Nonparametric, Case III", 5))
df3 <- data.frame(Method, Power, x= x3)


df_bind <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = 'method_id') # add data frame ids for method colouring. 

ggplot(df_bind, aes(x, Power)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = method_id, linetype = grepl('Parametric', Method))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'red', 'blue'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I have added the conditional statement for the line-type. To make this more elegant, you could either create a helper column with the same statement, or change the names/values via `scale_linetype_manual`

Comment: Is there a way to keep the 2 line types the same (only solid and dashed)? Also, Can I only have the original 3 colors (green, red, blue)?